# Trouble using Visual Studio with .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

sorry if I'm maybe asking a dumb question, but I have trouble creating projects and running them using .Net Core. The issue is as follows:

After creating a project, My menu bar up top has a lot less functionalities and I can't even start debugging. I can't even add a simple class to the project. I'll post a few screenshots, so you can see how am I creating my projects(in case I'm doing something wrong). Just to add, .Net Framework works just fine.

[Project Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpgyk.png)

[Name & Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCbxI.png)

[Target Framework. I've tried each one but none work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Kyx.png)

[When I try to run the empty project, it asks me to "attach to Process"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7GLm.png)

[Example of a "Project" menu, which has almost nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJZNt.png)

[Program.cs is listed within "Miscellaneous Files" and has no libraries included by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeUd4.png)

[Solution explorer is empty too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaaGh.png)

I don't have permission to embed pictures, sorry that it's this way. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It appears that the project isn't actually being associated to the Solution, which is causing all of these issues.  If you right click on the solution in solution explorer, and go to Add → Existing Project, find the .csproj file for your newly made project (where ever it is on disk) and add it, it should fix this.

Comment: Thanks, @TimothyG. but it still doesn't work. I've tried adding the .csproj but there was a popup saying "Unable to locate the .Net SDK.". After a bit of googling, I've checked system variables and added the dotnet folder from ProgramFiles to the system variables, as I couldn't find it inside. Even after that, along with a few uninstalls and reinstalls, I couldn't get it to work. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: "Unable to locate the .Net SDK" makes me think you don't have the .NET 5 SDK installed on your machine, but I would think Visual Studio wouldn't even give you the option to select that when making a new project if that was the case.  Run the Visual Studio Installer (search for it in Windows search), select the Modify button, and [check if the .NET 5 Runtime is installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgHkM.png) Install it if it isn't. If this doesn't work, can you try creating a new solution on your C:\ drive instead as a last ditch effort?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods to troubleshoot.

Check first if which .net Core SDK is available in the system.

Step 1: Open Command prompt (CMD) and type dotnet --info

If it shows "No SDKs were found".

Step 2: Install SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core

If you have an SDK environment, you can refer to the following practices:Try to edit envrionment Variables.

Right click on This PC -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables

Add [install path] C:\Program Files\dotnet\ to the variable path.

Restart visual studio.

If it does not solve this problem, you can refer to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk).

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately I've already tried all of this and nothing worked for me. Running the visual studio installer, I confirmed that .NET 5 Runtime is installed. Environment variables are in check and `dotnet --list-sdks` spits out the three versions I have installed. I created a new project with .NET Core 5.0 and specified the version in its root folder with a global.json file... Nothing. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling stuff manually (not through VS installer) and it still doesn't work... I have no ideas to what can I try else...

Comment: Have you installed the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the SDK? x64 and x86 versions of the SDK can't be active the same time.https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/20/Adventures-in-NET-SDK-Installation-SDKs-not-Showing-Up.In addition, there are too many possibilities to cause this kind of error. If you try a lot of methods and still can't work, the worst plan may need to reinstall the system.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Your comment has helped. The 64bit and 32bit versions cannot be installed at the same time. The issue, for some reason, is that when my VS updates, it populates the 32bit folder too, making me have to delete the whole folder... It's been a pain.